# remove CPU % from indicator multiload

Tags: unity, indicator, settings

[image]

Recently, Ubuntu indicator multiload start to show the CPU usage in percent (in the screenshot `CPU 3%` in my top bar.

I have no idea how I added it (may be a via a keyboard shortcut hit by error?), and I don't know how to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall, this is a bug. Open the preferences...

[image]

Click on Indicator Items...

[image]

Click the Add button and add an empty definition in front of the CPU definition. Use the Up button if need be to make it look exactly like what I've shown.

Comment: I already had an empty line before the CPU. Deleting it and recreating did the job. Thanks